# Apache Tike - possible values for color space

Tags: apache-tika, color-space

I'm using Apache Tika to extract metadata from an image file. It works good, but in order to analyse the results programmatically, I have to know what are the possible values for each property. Is there a document that describes that. I tried to dig into the code, but it is complicated and it did not take me anywhere.
For example, what are all the possible values for the property:
**Chroma ColorSpaceType** -->   **RGB, YCbCr, ...**

Answer (score 0):

Those values should be coming straight through from the Java javax.imageio code. Where possible, Tika tries to use and map onto well-known, externally defined Metadata specifications. For images, that's things like EXIF and XMP. However, there's the odd thing where either no good spec has been identified, or no-one has setup the mapping, and then the raw values from the underlying library are passed through. This is one such case.

For many of the metadata properties, the list of possible values is enumerated within the [Tika Property Definition](https://tika.apache.org/1.7/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Property.html), but sadly no-one has yet found the time to do so for this particular property ([patches very much welcome!](http://tika.apache.org/contribute.html)), so you'll need to check the EXIF spec for the values.

In order to find the possible values, you'll need to look at the javax.imageio source code itself! Crazy, but true, there's no constants for this defined on the interfaces, only hard coded strings within the code...

Probably your best place to start would be [the OpenJDK imageio jpeg implementation](https://svn.java.net/svn/jai-imageio-core~svn/trunk/src/share/classes/com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/jpeg/CLibJPEGMetadata.java), which seems to have most of the constants in. You'd also need to check the other image formats code in there too, in case they define more constants. Good luck, and please contribute a patch when you've managed it all!